# Recursive function: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, recursion, typeerror

I want my function to run again using recursion if the user gives invalid input, however I'm getting an error when the code runs:

```
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.
```

Here is my code.

```py
y = 'yes'
y1 ='Yes'
y2 = 'y'
y3 = 'Y' 

def triangle():
    triangle = raw_input('Is the triangle a 45-45-90 or a 30-60-90? ')
    if triangle == y:
        print 'yes'
    elif triangle == y1:
        print 'yes'
    elif triangle == y2:
        print 'yes'
    elif triangle == y3:
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'you must enter '+ y +' or ' + y1 + ' or ' + y + ' or ' + y3
        triangle()
```

Comment: Don't use the same name for the function and the user's input...

Comment: Use a different local variable name. It is conflicting with the function name. Also, you can use the 'in'  operator to check for the input value

Answer (score 2):

Since Python is a dynamic language, you are able to reassign a variable type from one to another - in this case, inadvertently.

When you set a variable with the equal `=` sign you are actually assigning not only the value, but the inferred type as well.

This little test can show you the variable type changing on the fly:

```
i = 1 
type(i) ## int
i = "s" 
type(i) ## str
```

To learn more about the dynamic nature and how variable assignment can change the type of a variable, see this link:
http://www.python-course.eu/variables.php

Here's the flow

1. Your function name is `triangle`
2. Immediately inside the function, you create a variable `triangle` which is an str
3. When your `else` block executes, it errors out because `triangle` is now an str and no longer a reference to the function `triangle()`

It's a good coding practice to name your variables somewhat representatively of what they contain - in this case, a user response;

The minor change of the variable name makes your program work :)

```
import math

y = 'yes'
y1 ='Yes'
y2 = 'y'
y3 = 'Y'

def triangle():
    response = raw_input('Is the triangle a 45-45-90 or a 30-60-90? ')
    if response == y:
        print 'yes'
    elif response == y1:
        print 'yes'
    elif response == y2:
        print 'yes'
    elif response == y3:
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'you must enter '+ y +' or ' + y1 + ' or ' + y + ' or ' + y3
        triangle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    triangle()
```

Bonus:

You can make your if/else block much simpler by using `in` especially since your response is always the same (print 'yes' and exit the program):

```
if response in (y, y1, y2, y3):
    print 'yes'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You created a string input called `triangle` which is also the name of your function. **Beware!**

Answer (score 0):

You assigned `triangle` to your `raw_input()`, which overrides your function declaration; thus, you are calling `'myinput'()`, instead of `triangle()`. To fix this, just change the name of your function or your `raw_input()` variable assignment.